# What are hidden fields in a Clarion .TPS file?

Tags: field, hidden, clarion, tps

I am looking at extracting some data from a Clarion .TPS file and I have been using the TopScan Application to open them.

When I look at the tables there are lots of hidden fields.

Are they just protected fields i.e. to stop someone from seeing the information or are they something to do with the indexes?

Also would using the ODBC driver reveal what they are?

Reards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you open a TPS table using Topscan, it only shows the first few columns (15 I think) and the rest are set as "hidden". This is only a feature of Topscan, not a developer or technical restriction.

To view them, click on the menu `Column` » `Show/Hide...`. It will show a dialog with all the columns in the table, click the button `Select all` and `OK` and all columns will be displayed.

After you close the table, a new file `tablename.SCN` will be created, it saves the visible/hidden status of the columns and any other changes you make the view (column width, position, picture, etc.)